# Post request in Postman

Tags: json, api, request, postman, localhost

I encountered such a problem through POSTMAN, I can’t send a POST request, what could be the problem?
POSTMAN CONSOLE:
`Error: localhost request not supported Network Request Headers User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2 Accept: */* Cache-Control: no-cache Postman-Token: 815c2340-5ac3-4ab4-91be-8d62a5d6333b Host: localhost:8800 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Connection: keep-alive`

```
import User from "../models/user.model.js";

export const register = async (req,res)=> {
    try {
        const newUser = new User(req.body);
        
        await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).send("User has been created.");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
    }
};


//export const login = async (req,res)=> {};

//export const logout = async (req,res)=> {};
```

```
import express from "express";
import { register,  } from "../controllers/auth.controller.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", register)
//router.post("/login", login)
//router.post("/logout", logout)

export default router;
```

[image]
[image]

I'm a beginner and this is my first time using POSTMAN so don't judge too harshly)

Answer (score 0):

Try to off postman-generated headers.[Hidden headers On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zi3f.png)
And send again.[Hidden headers Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBRo0.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).